# how to migrate multiple taxonomy terms?

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a an array like this from json.

```
[terms] => Array
  (
    [0] => Array
      (
        [id] => 1
        [Name] => term 1
      )
    [1] => Array
      (
        [id] => 2
        [Name] => term 2
      )
    [2] => Array
      (
       [id] => 3
       [Name] => term 3
      )
    [3] => Array
      (
       [id] => 4
       [Name] => term 4
      )
  )
```

I want to migrate them as taxonomy terms.

```
name:
    - plugin: sub_process
      source: terms
      process:
        value: Name
```

but this only migrate the firs term. `term 1`.

how will I migrate all?

Comment: were you able to solve this? trying to do something similar. Any help would be appreciated. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299768/import-multi-level-json-using-migrate-api

Comment: @miststudent2011 check my answer.

Comment: Can you pls have a look into my question and suggest solution if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code to fix my problem.

```
keywords:
    - plugin: sub_process
      source: keyword
      process:
        value: Name
    - plugin: entity_generate
      value_key: name
      bundle_key: vid
      bundle: keyword
      entity_type: taxonomy_term
      ignore_case: true
```

I put it in the nodes migration file.