# Import multi level JSON using Migrate API

Tags: 8, migrations

I am trying to import countries list and its corresponding timezones using Migration API's JSON parser plugin .

I am trying to import timezones in paragraphs.

I have created a paragraph to import timezones with text fields. I am able to import data if country has only one timezone. But can not import if country has multiple timezones. Multiple timezones are structured as an array in JSON file.

Can anyone guide me how to iterate multi level JSON.

```
id: countries_timezones_json_import
label: JSON feed of Countries Time Zones.

migration_group: countries_list

migration_tags:
  - Countries List JSON Source
  - Countries timezones Import

dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - countries_list_migration
source:
  # We use the JSON source plugin.
  plugin: url
  # Specifies the http fetcher plugin.
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  # Specifies the JSON parser plugin.
  data_parser_plugin: json
  headers:
    Accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    Content-Type: 'application/json'

  # One or more URLs from which to fetch the source data.
  urls:
    - https://del.dog/raw/countries-list

  include_raw_data: true

  item_selector: /

  fields:
    -
      name: field_country_id
      label: 'Country ID'
      selector: id
    -
      name: field_country_name
      label: 'Country Name'
      selector: name
    -
      name: field_country_iso3
      label: 'Country ISO3'
      selector: iso3
    -
      name: field_country_iso2
      label: 'Country ISO2'
      selector: iso2
    -
      name: field_country_phone_code
      label: 'Country Phone Code'
      selector: phone_code
    -
      name: field_country_capital
      label: 'Country Capital'
      selector: capital
    -
      name: field_country_currency
      label: 'Country Currency'
      selector: currency
    -
      name: field_country_currency_symbol
      label: 'Country Currency Symbol'
      selector: currency_symbol
    -
      name: field_country_native
      label: 'Country Native'
      selector: native
    -
      name: field_country_region
      label: 'Country Region'
      selector: region
    -
      name: field_country_subregion
      label: 'Country Sub Region'
      selector: subregion
    -
      name: field_country_abbreviation
      label: 'Country Abbreviation'
      selector: timezones/0/abbreviation
    -
      name: field_country_gmt_offset
      label: 'Country GMT Offset'
      selector: timezones/0/gmtOffset
    -
      name: field_country_gmt_offset_name
      label: 'Country GMT Offset Name'
      selector: /timezones/0/gmtOffsetName
    -
      name: field_country_tz_name
      label: 'Country TZ Name'
      selector: /timezones/0/tzName
    -
      name: field_country_zone_name
      label: 'Country Zone Name'
      selector: /timezones/0/zoneName

  ids:
    field_country_id:
      type: integer

process:

  field_country_abbreviation:
   -
      plugin: default_value
      source: field_country_abbreviation
      default_value: 'NA'

  field_country_gmt_offset:
   -
      plugin: default_value
      source: field_country_gmt_offset
      default_value: 'NA'

  field_country_gmt_offset_name:
   -
      plugin: default_value
      source: field_country_currency
      default_value: 'NA'

  field_country_tz_name:
   -
      plugin: default_value
      source: field_country_tz_name
      default_value: 'NA'

  field_country_zone_name:
   -
      plugin: default_value
      source: field_country_zone_name
      default_value: 'NA'

destination:
  plugin: entity_reference_revisions:paragraph
  default_bundle: country_timezones

migration_dependencies:
  required: {}
  optional: {}
```

[image: country_timezones paragraph structure]
I am having difficulty in iterating `timezones` array. In the [JSON Data](https://del.dog/raw/countries-list)

I thought of setting `item_selector` value as `/timezones` but this array doesnt have a unique identifier and it can also be linked to country.

**Edit 1:**

So after browsing the available resources I am able to process the input data to add unique timezoneId to each time zones and respective ids to parent id by creating a `data_parser_plugin`. Inspired from [here](https://www.nikunj.dev/migrating-multi-value-non-associative-data)

Updated data is in [this](https://del.dog/raw/countries-list-new) format.

Now still I am having difficulty to find a way to process sub array. I can not find a way to process the data using `sub_process` plugin.